# String conversion error occurs unity WS server

Tags: typescript, unity-game-engine, websocket, server

I'm trying to make a web socket server using typescript and use it for Unity(client). However, for some reasons, the string conversion error occurs from Unity. My friends also used my socket server code and used it on Unity;but, errors didn't occur. After that, I tried my client code on another project, but the same error occurred. Well, I'm using Korean for my computer language, but I couldn't find any Korean in my project directory.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class SocketManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ClientWebSocket _socket = null;

    private void Start()
    {
        Connection();
    }

    public async void Connection()
    {
        Debug.Log("Starting Connection");
        if (_socket != null && _socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket already connected");
            return;
        }

        _socket = new ClientWebSocket();
        Uri serverUri = new Uri("ws://localhost:50000");

        await _socket.ConnectAsync(serverUri, CancellationToken.None);

        Debug.Log("Connected");

        ArraySegment<byte> bufferSegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
        WebSocketReceiveResult result = await _socket.ReceiveAsync(bufferSegment, CancellationToken.None);

        string msg = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufferSegment.Array);
        Debug.Log(msg);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        Disconnect();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            _socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure,
                               "Quit",
                               CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
}
```

My WS server code:

```typescript
import Express, { Application } from 'express';
import {IncomingMessage} from 'http'
import WS from 'ws';

const App: Application = Express();

const httpServer = App.listen(50000, ()=>{
    console.log("Server is running on 50000 port");
});

const socketServer : WS.Server = new WS.Server({
    server:httpServer,
    //port:9090
}, () => {
    console.log("Socket server is running on 50000 port");
});

socketServer.on("connection", (soc:WS, req:IncomingMessage) => {
    payload: Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(20);
    soc.send("Welcome to My Server!");
});
```

The Error

> ExecutionEngineException: String conversion error: Illegal byte sequence encounted in the input.
> System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName (System.String hostName) (at :0)
> System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry (System.String hostNameOrAddress) (at :0)
> System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses (System.String hostNameOrAddress) (at :0)
> (wrapper delegate-end-invoke) .end_invoke_IPAddress[]__this___IAsyncResult(System.IAsyncResult)
> System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostAddresses (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) (at :0)
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) (at :0)
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Comment: Why are you using _web sockets_ in a **game**?  You should use normal sockets if the intent is for realtime multiplayer games. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=net-6.0

Comment: ...also I wouldn't be surprised if `ClientWebSocket` uses `HttpClient` under the hood.  If so the latter with it's **inability to detect DNS changes** and desire for existence in a DI container is problematic for a game. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0#remarks

Comment: @MickyD in WebGL e.g. normal sockets afaik might not be available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your computer name have a double byte character in it? I found this post with a similar error: https://forum.unity.com/threads/string-conversion-error-illegal-byte-sequence-encounted.963213/

It does look like the code is failing during DNS lookup.  Maybe try changing your computer name and see if that helps. Also, maybe compare your friend's computer's name... I'm guessing they don't have a double byte character?

Comment: That helped a lot thanks! my computer name had Korean.